# Every finite integral extension of a Henselian, pseudo-geometric and analytically normal ring is algebraically closed in its completion.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings, hensels-lemma

In the book *Local Rings* Nagata states in Theorem 44.1:

> If $R$ is a Henselian pseudo-geometric analytically
>   normal ring, then every finite integral extension $R'$ of $R$ is analytically irreducible and is algebraically closed in its completion $\widehat{R'}$ (i.e., every
>   element of $\widehat{R'}$ which is algebraic over $R'$ is already in $R'$).

In the (short) proof he deduces from the fact if some $c$ is integral over $R'$ and $R'[c] \otimes_{R'} \widehat{R'}$ is an integral domain that $c \in R'$. 
My question is: How does this follow? I think the Henselian property must be used at this point, because it is not used anywhere else and I believe the statement is wrong without this assumption. But I just don't see how it holds.

Thank you for advice in advance.